# CherryPy encoding: bool object not iterable

Tags: cherrypy, qualtrics

---

Hello, 
I am using CherryPy to host the gui of an application that takes json files from qualtrics and drops them in a mysql server.

The code seems to work for most surveys but for some I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\jam66\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 627, in respond    
    self._do_respond(path_info)

File "C:\Users\jam66\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\_cprequest.py", line 686, in _do_respond
    response.body = self.handler()

File "C:\Users\jam66\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 264, 
    in __call__ct.params['charset'] = self.find_acceptable_charset()

File "C:\Users\jam66\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site- packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 173, in find_acceptable_charset
     if encoder(self.default_encoding):

File "C:\Users\jam66\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\cherrypy\lib\encoding.py", line 114, in encode_string 
     for chunk in self.body:

TypeError: 'bool' object is not iterable
```

Any help on beginning to understand this issues is appreciated

Comment: Sorry, more details and actual code with handler needed to answer this fully. Also, it would be nice to see actual HTTP payload you're sending there.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that some of your exposed methods are returning a boolean. You have to return a string or an iterable. Unless you are using the json tool, in that case the dictionary to string is handled by the tool.

As a way to debug it, just print or log the value that would will be returned, verify the type with the type function.